# Is the most secure way of viewing an infected pdf file through a cloud pdf reader like xodo using a pdf uploaded to Google Drive?

Tags: virus, pdf

Is the most secure way of viewing an infected pdf file through a cloud pdf reader like xodo using a pdf uploaded to Google Drive?

I have a work laptop and I currently work for a small startup that had their database wiped out by a ransomware, so every usb drives are disabled and cannot be used to upload files to my laptop, so I was wondering if it would 100% safe to view pdf files using xodo and Google Drive? If not, what are better alternatives? My work laptop is a ThinkPad by Lenovo with the latest Windows.

Comment: There are many ways to securely handle potential malware. However **step #1** is always "**Know what you are doing**".